# Storing client scripts in asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is suggested location for clients scripts (jquery, javascript) that are used in a single view and are not reused in any other view.

It does not make sense to put it in /Scripts/ folder since it is difficult to keep track of all the different scripts.

What about using /Scripts/{Viewname}/ folders and maybe use it for bundling?

Comment: The suggested location is ~/Scripts. You can essentially create a folder anywhere in the root directory of your solution and reference that, however my suggestion would be to be creative with your Scripts folder. You can separate the specific client scripts into grouped sub folders as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bosman is right, be creative in your Scripts folder. Here is how I organize my **view-specific-scripts**.

I organize them using following format:

```
Scripts/Views/{controller}.{view}.js // Doesn't belong to any area.
Scripts/Views/{area}.{controller}.{view}.js
```

I group the scripts into a folder called "Views" to indicate that they are view-specific-scripts.

Here is what it typically looks like

```
Scripts/Views/home.index.js
Scripts/Views/admin.users.index.js
Scripts/Views/admin.users.create.js
Scripts/jquery.js
Scripts/jquery.min.js
```

If you rely too much on Javascripts, you can group them further by **area**

```
Scripts/Views/{area}/{controller}.{view}.js

Scripts/Views/home.index.js
Scripts/Views/Admin/users.index.js
Scripts/Views/Admin/users.create.js
```

No need to bundle them, you can reference the scripts directly in the View.

```
// Located at the bottom of the view.
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Views/admin.users.index.js")
```